# How to filter dataframe only by month and year?

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to select many cells which are filtered only by month and year. For example there are `01.01.2017`, `15.01.2017`, `03.02.2017` and `15.02.2017` cells. I want to group these cells just looking at the month and year information. If they are in january, They should be grouped together.

Output Expectation:

```
01.01.2017 ---- 1
15.01.2017 ---- 1
03.02.2017 ---- 2
15.02.2017 ---- 2
```

Edit: I have 2 datasets in different excels as you can see below.

[first data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FQgr.png)

[second data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQObk.png)

What I m trying to do is that I want to get 'Su Seviye' data for every 'DH_ID' seperately from first data. And then I want to paste these data into 'Kuyu Yüksekliği' column in the second data. But the problems are that every 'DH_ID' is in different sheets and although there are only month and year data in first database, second database has day information additionally. How can I produce this kind of codes?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('...Gözlem kuyu su seviyeleri- 2017.xlsx', sheet_name= 'GÖZLEM KUYULARI1', header=None)


df2 = pd.read_excel('...YERALTI SUYU GÖZLEM KUYULARI ANALİZ SONUÇLAR3.xlsx', sheet_name= 'HJ-8')


HJ8 = df.iloc[:, [0,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29]]


##writer = pd.ExcelWriter('yıllarsuseviyeler.xlsx')

##HJ8.to_excel(writer)

##writer.save()

rb = pd.read_excel('...yıllarsuseviyeler.xlsx')

rb.loc[0,7]='01.2022'
rb.loc[0,9]='02.2022'
rb.loc[0,11]='03.2022'
rb.loc[0,13]='04.2022'
rb.loc[0,15]='05.2021'
rb.loc[0,17]='06.2022'
rb.loc[0,19]='07.2022'
rb.loc[0,21]='08.2022'
rb.loc[0,23]='09.2022'
rb.loc[0,25]='10.2022'
rb.loc[0,27]='11.2022'
rb.loc[0,29]='12.2022'
```

You can see what I have done above.

Comment: create new column only with month and year - and later you can use this column to filter or group rows.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: when I look at output then I think you means rather `sorting` by month and year. But this also can be simpler if you add column only with month and year. And if you have dates as strings then you could use `.str[3:]` to get only `01.2017` and `02.2017`

Comment: btw: if you would keep date as string `2017.01.15` or convert to objects `DateTIme` then you would sort it without using special functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, how can I reach you? I would like to explain all the processes to you.

Comment: describe problem in question.

Comment: I edited as you said.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can convert `date` column to Datetime object, then get the year and month part with `to_period`, at last get the group number with `ngroup()`.

```py
df['group'] = df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y').dt.to_period('M')).ngroup() + 1
```

```
         date  group
0  01.01.2017      1
1  15.01.2017      1
2  03.02.2017      2
3  15.02.2017      2
```